# Can't find the provider I booked a holiday with

Tags: bookings

I have booked a holiday and can't remember which company I booked with. I have a reference number starting with NIB. Can anyone advise me at all?

Comment: How long is this reference number? Is it roughly six characters like 921AT5 (not a real booking number)? If so, it could be an airline reference number, which would be a big clue. Beyond that, maybe try checking your bank or credit card statements. You had to pay for the trip somehow, so perhaps you have a record that would tell you who you made the payment to?

Comment: Country would help too.

Comment: If you made a call on a cell phone it may still remember the phone number. Searching for that number may find the web site where you got the phone number.

Comment: Did you not get any confirmation in your email or anything ?

Comment: I voted to reopen the question as it seems clear and relevant but could you provide more info, basically anything you remember could help, format of the number, where you are located, destination, type of holiday (are we talking about a package holiday, cruise, flight?)